# Why does the React app give an error when "npm start" command is run?

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, npm-install

[image]

I was working on a react.js app 2 years ago on my old machine, recently I downloaded the code-base on my new machine and tried running the app using the "npm install" and "npm start" commands, that's how I used to successfully run it on my old machine but its now giving me the error described in the image.

On several forums I was advised to delete the node_modules folder, then run the "npm install" again and that should fix the issue but on my side it doesn't.

Comment: did you try clean or verify npm cache with npm cache verify and  npm cache clean --force command ?

Comment: #0 it seams that your screnshot is not the error log. Is just a warning #1 share us your package.json #2 your project seams to be bugy :s. If is a standard CRA react project, search a new one on github and use its package.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the install with yarn instead npm?
`yarn install`

Comment: Yes but it says "'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Please try `npm install -g yarn` first and `yarn install` again.